# Android App that needs access to the browser to log into a website

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-wifi

I would like to wite an app that logs into a web site automatically. Here's why. I take light rail in San Jose, and they have free Wifi. However, everytime you reconnect, you need to go the browser, check a box, and then click submit.

ATT has an app that will auto-login to wifi via a web site at Starbuck, so there must be a way. I assume it has to do with snooping on wifi, and then simulating a browser.

Anyone have any suggestions? Would this be a Service or an Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [Android Login](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/) is something in the area your looking for, assuming your doing your own coding.

Comment: Thanks @Sirisak, but No, not quite. Here is what I want to do. When I see that my system has connected to aa Wifi SSID that I know is a VTA wifi system, I want to then programmatically call up a page (my guess using a webkit object), check a box, and then submit the form so I can use wifi. THis is similar to what ATT's app does for attwifi hotspots. Make sense?